# Is it possible to copy text to my Windows 10 clipboard from tmux on PuTTY using vim key bindings?

Tags: tmux

I have a tmux session running in PuTTY, and I have tmux configured to use vim keybindings. I want to be able to use the visual highlight mode that vim keybindings provide (shift+V I believe), highlight some text, and then copy it to my Windows 10 clipboard. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running tmux remotely.

If so, then for this to work you need a terminal that supports OSC 52. From a quick look at the putty code it doesn't appear to, so you will not be able to do this with putty.

However, you could try a different terminal that does support it, like mintty - it looks like you just need to turn its AllowSetSelection option on. IIRC mintty defaults to TERM=xterm, so if your tmux is new enough and you turn this option on, it should just work.

If it doesn't work, you need to check that Ms is set in the terminal-overrides option for the TERM you have outside tmux, and that the tmux set-clipboard option is set to on or external.